# Connection refused error in Java Socket

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to build a software that will allow remote PC control.My code so far has been able to share the server screen to the client when both the client and the server are on the same PC but it shows the "Connection refused" error when I try to keep the clients and servers in different laptops.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, 
 ClassNotFoundException {

    DrawGui();
     ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(3389);
    //Socket server = ss.accept();
    while(true)
    {
    Socket server = ss.accept();
    new ReceiveScreenshots(server,frame,desktop,inter,panel,label);
    }

}
```

I was advised to keep ss.accept() out of the while loop. But if I change my code to the following and keep the ss.accept() out of the while loop, my code shows numerous errors.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    DrawGui();
     ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(3389);
    Socket server = ss.accept();
    while(true)
    {
    //Socket server = ss.accept();
    new ReceiveScreenshots(server,frame,desktop,inter,panel,label);
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me please? Below is the code for the client

```
  public class Test {
 public static void main(String args[]) throws AWTException, IOException
 {
    Socket s = new Socket("localhost",3389);
    Robot robot = null;
    GraphicsEnvironment gen = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gdev = gen.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    robot = new Robot(gdev);
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(dim);
    new Client(s,robot,rectangle);

}
}

public class Client extends Thread {

Socket s;
Rectangle rectangle = null;

Robot robot = null;
ImageIcon previous = new ImageIcon();
public Client(Socket s, Robot robot, Rectangle rectangle) {

    this.s = s;
    this.rectangle = rectangle;
    this.robot = robot;
    start();
}

public void run() {
    ObjectOutputStream ous = null;
    try {
        ous = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    while (true) {
        BufferedImage bImage = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(bImage);
        if(previous.equals(image))
            continue;
        else
        {
        try {
            System.out.println("before sending image");
            ous.writeObject(image);
            System.out.println(" image sent");
            ous.reset();
            System.out.println(" stream reset");
            previous = image;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }}
```

}

Comment: If the client and server are run on different hosts, have you ensured that you can reach the client from the server (ie necessary ports are forwarded/open)?

Comment: @Zachary I am currently not using port forwarding as the laptops are connected with the same router. The second code snippet that I have provided with shows errors even when the client and the server are on the same PC. I should have mentioned that in my post, sorry

Comment: The second one infinitely creates new ReceiveScreenshots Objects without any delay. The first segment works because ss.accept() blocks until a connection is made, and waits for another connection before repeating itself. I don't know what error it is throwing, but this may the cause.

Comment: The Connection refused error will be because the two hosts cannot communicate. If this is occurring when the server/client are on the same host, it will be due to an issue with providing the wrong address (it should be 127.0.0.1 or localhost) or it will be an error with the code in the client server.

Comment: So should I create some delay before calling the ReceiveScreenshots class?

Comment: I don't know what ReceiveScreenshots() is. If it had an InputStream you should only have one per client session (which is what the first segment does). If the object requests a single screenshot then you should reconsider how you have laid out your code.

Comment: It throws StreamCorruptedException and NullPointerException if I do not delay the calls to ReceiveScrenshots class

Comment: That is because you have multiple Objects manipulating the OutputStream/InputStreams for a single socket connection. You need to either have the first segment or remove the while loop altogether. The reason why you would want a SocketServer.accept() in a loop is to accept multiple connections. This is a problem with you being unsure how your code should be formatted, which you need to decide on.

Comment: ReceiveScreenshot is a class that has an ObjectInputStream. It receives the screenshots that the client is sending and it calls another class GenerateClientScreen that draws the Client screen on a panel. Since the client is sending lots of screenshots, I thought that an infinite loop is required that will continuously receive them, please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: If you're wanting some further help, [Join this discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162242/discussion-thenoob) and I can try help in more detail.

Comment: @Zachary that is really nice of you but I am new in this website and it requires 20 points to start a discussion chat but I don't have that much

Comment: You should be able to join the discussion link I provided now.

Comment: sorry @Zachary it is still the same.

Comment: @Zachary I have earned 21 points but am still not being able to enter the discussion unfortunaltely

Comment: @Zachary 'The two hosts cannot communicate' is just waffle, and applies to any connect exception. 'Connection refused' has a very specific meaning.

Comment: @EJP I understand what you mean. Assuming it works when the Server and Client were launched on the same computer, the most probable reason for the connection is because the two hosts are not configured to communicate properly (ie. host A is unable to reach host B). This could be down to a firewall issue, you are using a global IP address when both hosts are on the same network and ports have not correctly been configured, etc.

Comment: @Zachary No it isn't. The most probable reason for a connection refusal is that nothing was listening at the target IP:port. A configuration problem would result in a connect timeout, host unreachable, no route to host, etc. You continue to give generic solutions to specific problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no code here that can throw `ConnectException: connection refused`, but it means that nothing was listening at the target IP:port.

You were 'advised to keep `ss.accept()` out of the `while` loop' by whom? On what grounds?

```
Socket s = new Socket("localhost",3389);
```

This code only works if the server is in, err, the local host. If it isn't, you have to provide the IP address or hostname where it is, instead of `"localhost"`. Surely this is obvious?

Comment: By a senior in my university who has done the same project. Could you please elaborate what "nothing was listening at the target IP:port" means?

Comment: @TheNoob "connection refused" means either 1) the client is trying to connect a socket to an IP:port that does not have a server socket actively listening on it; 2) the server is listening, but has too many pending connections waiting acceptance; or 3) the connection is being blocked, such as by a firewall. And the senior is wrong.

Comment: By me (and trust me, I am senior to your senior): could you please complete your question by posting the client code that incurs this exception? So that I can exhibit where your problem lies?

Comment: @EJP I have updated my question. Would you please give it a look?

Comment: @EJP I have already tried replacing "localhost" with the IP of the PC I am trying to connect with. It still is not working. In the meantime I also tried to update my code by keeping the accept() out of the while loop and it is showing me errors. Thank you for explaining why I should not keep the accept out of the loop but the "connection refused" is still there, I'm afraid

Comment: @TheNoob Are you using a private or public address?

Comment: 'Still not working' is not a problem description, and neither is 'still showing me errors' Do you get the same error? A different error? Timeout? Nothing? NB I haven't explained why you should not keep the `accept()` out of the loop. I am asking you where you got this mad idea. It isn't the same thing.

Comment: @Zachary I am using a public address

Comment: @Zachary It is obvious from the connection refusal that the target IP address was reachable from the source IP address. It is a positive error resulting from an RST response to the initial SYN segment. Again, if it was a network connectivity problem it would have been a different error.

Comment: @EJP Forgive my ignorance, but if he's using a public address that is allocated to his network, he would get the same refusal. The address is reachable, but it may not reach the intended target as he has not configured his network correctly. (Ie two hosts are on the same network and have internet access through a single IP address. The router allocates a private address to each host, so if you used the public address you would need to ensure you reach the intended host).

Comment: @EJP I apologize for the confusion. What I'm trying to say is that if Host A and Host B are reachable with the public IP X, the router may forward traffic on Port 3389 to Host A instead of Host B. X is reachable from A, however, A will not be listening on 3389 (As B is), hence resulting in the observed behavior.

Comment: @EJP even if I change the localhost and set it to the IP of the server, it shows "connection refused" error

Comment: @EJP the code is runnning perfectly now. Not sure why it was showing "connection refused" even after replacing the "localhost" with the IP of my server for some time. But it is working properly now. Thank you so much

Comment: @Zachary If the router doesn't forward traffic as you describe, the target IP address:port won't receive the SYN, and won't issue the RST, and the client won't get 'connection refused'. He will get some other error. Third time I have stated this.

Comment: @EJP If the syn packet does make it to Host B, the rst packet will be sent if it is not listening on that port. But, if it does forward as I said, where the syn packet is sent to Host A by the router, then Host A will send a rst packet just the same. It is possible that the syn is sent to the wrong host and a rst still be received.